# FTP script not transferring files to local computer

Tags: virtual-machine, batch, ftp, hyper-v

I'm running a batch file that calls a script from a text file but it's not retrieving the files I want.

DownloadData.bat

```
ftp -v -i -s:FTPscript.txt 192.168.50.50
```

FTPscript.txt

```
username
password
lcd "c:\temp"
cd /Downloads
pwd
binary
mget "*.csv"
disconnect
bye
```

Result

```
C:\temp>ftp -v -i -s:FTPscript 192.168.50.50
User (192.168.50.50:(none)):

ftp> lcd c:\temp
Local directory now C:\temp.
ftp> cd /Downloads
ftp> pwd
257 /Downloads/ is the current working directory.
ftp> binary
ftp> mget "*.csv"
Cannot find list of remote files.
ftp> disconnect
ftp> bye
```

What am I doing wrong? This may be irrelevant but I am running this script off a virtual machine using windows 10 hyper-v. The VM is windows 7.

edit 2021-05-14--- Couldn't figure it out so I am using winSCP instead which is working. Thanks for the responses everyone!

Comment: If you have a "solution", please post it as an answer, instead of editing the qeustion.

Answer (score 2):

`mget "*.csv"` might be failing for these reasons:

- There's no .csv files in the remote Downloads directory.
- Permission issue - the FTP user doesn't have read or list permissions on the remote Downloads directory.
- You have a strange FTP server that's not responding to the FTP protocol `LIST` or `NLST` request with something Windows `ftp` expects, or your FTP server doesn't support wildcard filenames.